# Is there a way to set a delay between sending messages with Mautic segment broadcast mail merges?

Tags: email, mailmerge, mautic

I'm using Gsuite for SMTP outgoing server, and Google sometimes flags me as spam if I send large mail merges. With Gmass and Yesware and other solutions, there is a delay between messages, so they don't get sent out immediately, like a "throttling" delay.

Is this possible using Mautic broadcast segments?

My goal is to wait 1-5 minutes between sending individual messages.

[image]

These are the Gmass settings to do this:

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into batching your mail sends with your Mautic cron jobs - it might not be exactly what you're looking for, but you could use this to effectively throttle the number being processed.

Take a look at this forum post: https://forum.mautic.org/t/cron-jobs-whats-the-difference/11177/3?u=rcheesley which has lots of useful information and links to other articles on optimising cron jobs.

The down side of that approach is that it would take longer to process your queue, but if that's not an issue then it should be fine.

Comment: I looked in there, but can't find any cron that throttles individual messages, the queues can be delayed though, but that doesn't help me